# PHP Graphics Encoding Error

Tags: php, netbeans, png, xampp, gd

I am having problems with producing a Rectangle with GD - PHP. I am running XAMPP and programming on Netbeans IDE. I am new to PHP but some what fimilar with Perl.

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");

  $newImg = ImageCreate(250,250);

  $red = ImageColorAllocate($newImg,255,0,0);

  ImageFill($newImg,0,0,$red);

  ImagePNG($newImg);

  ImageDestroy($newImg);
?>
```

Here is the out put.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
‰PNG


IHDRúú²"È~PLTEˆÁÿ·¿~`IDAThíÁ‚ ÿ¯nH@¿ :F¨z’IEND®B`‚    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stuff the html into a seperate file, and use a `<img>` tag to load your php script, e.g.

```
<html>

<body>

<img src="yourimagescript.php" />

</body>

</html>
```

alternative, you COULD use data uris to embed the image directly into the html, but that brings about another set of problems, e.g.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(imagepng($newImg, '-')) ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use binary as source for image you need to use it as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,data..."/>
```

or if you want use it as it is in your example you need to point image src attribute to your php script from example

```
<img src="path/to/script.php"/>
```

and path/to/script.php"/ displays only data and correct header

> ‰PNG
>
> IHDRúú²"È~PLTEˆÁÿ·¿~`IDAThíÁ‚ ÿ¯nH@¿ :F¨z’IEND®B`‚